# Как можно реализовать в cms аналогичное примеру?

Tags: javascript, cms

Имеется следующий [пример](http://genplan.grnw.ru/).

Интересует как реализован генплан посёлка с возможностью показа по отдельным меткам и всплывающими подсказками.
Есть предположение, что реализовано с помощью какого-то плагина для Drupal или это на самописной cms.

Вопрос:
Подскажите любые варианты реализации подобного генплана на cms?
И возможно ли такое реализовать именно с помощью CMS Made Simple?

Comment: Это не плагин. И ничего сверх сложного в этом скрипте нет, тем более написан он как-то коряво, с перезагрузкой страницы. Такое может написать любой JavaScript-программист со стажем от года.

Comment: Lucky, но по Вашему мнению это сделано ручками, не через какой-н. модуль cms, где можно было бы удобно менять информацию об участках в случае необходимости?

Comment: Я кажется понял в чем корявость скрипта. При нажатии на домик он переходит по ссылке (не сразу, потому что перезагрузка не сразу происходит). Я не думаю, что это было так задумано :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример для CMS Drupal: берем стандартный модуль Views, выводим из базы домики в виде каталога с нужными полями (все поля скрываем, показываем только номер дома). Вставляем карту-картинку в body как background и позиционируем через CSS каждый домик в нужное место на картинке. К каждому домику через js привязываем обработчик клика и по клику показываем скрытые поля во всплывающем окошке. Фильтр (который ниже карты) будет чуть сложнее сделать, но при знании jQuery тоже не проблема.

Answer (score 2):

Никаких реализаций вы скорее всего не найдёте. Оно написано полностью ручками для данного сайта.